# Short Link of Artifacts of Last Failed Build

Tags: jenkins

How do you create a short link on the jenkins project page similar to the link "Last Successful Artifacts" but with the artifacts of the last **failed** build?

We have some jobs that only generate some logs when the build fails and such a link would be very handy.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sidebar link plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin) Has a feature that will make it possible to add a custom link on a project page (build/general too, but you want project). Then you can set that link to point to something like

```
${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/lastFailedBuild/artifact/
```

Another option is [Doclinks plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/DocLinks+Plugin) which does essentially the same.